# How can I make a div overlap?

Tags: html, css

Hi there guys I'm having an issue with a DIV basically as you see in the photo below the TAG is overlapping the menu drop down. Is it possible for the menu drop down to be priorty over the HR tag?

[image: Screenshot]

CSS FOR HR:

```
hr {
position:relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: try to give z-index value for dropdown more than hr like: .menu ul li{ z-index:9;} hr{z-index:0}

Comment: @Kiran Still not working :/

Comment: post your code in fiddle to solve this issue..

Comment: try -ve z-index value for hr tag?

Comment: Personally I would ditch the `<hr>` and place a `border-top` on each section instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, on your menu add a z-index so the dropdown appears over the hr.

```
.menu
{
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
}
```

You need to give it a position of relative as well for z-index to work.

Comment: Vibe, thanks your answer was correct but I can't click answer yet need to wait a few mins. Thanks

Comment: No worries Sally. Nico - didn't know that, I rarely ever use position: static;

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the `z-index` value of the `div` is smaller than that of the `hr`

Comment: This isn't really an answer... In the future, post information like this as a comment.

Comment: I beg to differ. The question was "How is this possible" and while I did not supply a complete block of code to fix the problem it is still a completely valid answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `position: relative` to your `.menu`